# Select a tab in Selenium by window name

Tags: java, selenium

I can open new tabs with openWindow(url,windowID) in Selenium(Java) but I can not switch back to them. I have tried with selectWindow and selectPopup but nothing happened. I have studied that I can do that by pressing(virtually) CTRL + tab number. I haven't tried because this is not good enough for me because I need more than 10 tabs.
How can a switch between tabs?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/731817/469210

Answer (score 2):

if you want to return to return to your original window, meaning the one your `selenium` test actually opened, just select "null" as the target id/ title. In addition, you can avoid clutter in different windows and tabs with the `wd.close();` command, in case you didn't know. This will not close all the tabs in your window, so you should be able to continue testing within these targets,